# local database to store information on ionic1

Tags: ionic-framework

I wanted you to advise me please to integrate a local database to my application to store information. This is the panorama. I will develop a mobile app that consists of the following problem:

the users that manage the application will access places where there is no internet connection (the signal is very bad), when there is an internet connection, the information will be synchronized to a database like SQL SERVER (it would be through web services) .

simply the name, order and product of a user would be stored.
I would like you to recommend a local database that works well on android and ios, and that allows the optimum performance for my application and allows queries to be made, such as searching by name or something, knowing how many records it allows to store and if this would make the app weigh too much, are things I want to know.
thank you very much.